# So what is the most likely answer for what happened to M5-BZ?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars: The Clone Wars episode Point of No Return, [M5-BZ](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/M5-BZhttp://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/M5-BZ) sacrifices himself by ejecting buzz droids and himself into hyperspace. An organic being would be atomized but BZ is mechanical. So what would happen to him? Will he drift in the superluminal tunnel for all of eternity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A **null quantum field generator** was a vital part of a hyperdrive unit. It stabilized the hyperspace corridor from collapsing during flight, as well as shielded the ship from the harmful energies and the gravitational forces of hyperspace. Its primary function was to keep the craft from prematurely leaving hyperspace.

(src: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Null_quantum_field_generator)

Since the droid had no such generator, ejecting into the hyperspace would either destroy it, or drop it into normalspace far from any celestial body (effectively stranding it forever).

I'm not aware of any canon info to further clarify which of the two options would happen.